# Can I point a branch to a new HEAD in mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

We have two major release branches - 'stable' and 'beta'. Over time, the 'beta' branch has received changes that didn't progress to stable, but were never removed.

What I'd like to do is sync beta with stable again so they are exactly the same. Is this possible with mercurial while keeping the same branch names?

We have rudimentary deployment set up for beta where a receive commit on the branch pushes out to all the webservers. I *could* just start a new branch off stable, but that would cause confusion.

Essentially I want to do this:

```
hg update stable
hg branch beta --overwrite
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Backout-solution**

In order to exclude from result (not in history of branch) you can a) backout "stalled" changesets in beta branch b) merge stable to beta

**Rebase-solution**

Create additional branch, rebase unwanted changesets to this branch, merge stable to beta

**MQ-solution**

Install mq, convert changesets-in-question into MQ-patches, unapply all mq-pathes, merge stable to beta

Addition

### If unwanted changesets in beta are unknown

(Ry4an graph used as source for commands)

**Diff-patch way**

Idea: adding "correcting changeset" on top of beta, which  bring bring beta to a the state, identical to state of branch stable@6

Implementation: `hg up beta & hg diff -r beta -r stable | hg import - & hg commit -m "Beta synced"`

**New branch way**

Idea: forgot about old outdated branch beta, create beta from scratch, current state of stable

Implementation: `hg up beta & hg commit -m "Closing branch" --close-branch & hg up stable & hg branch -F beta & ... & hg commit -m "Reopen new beta"`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know which change sets are bad or unwanted. Commit messages aren't very helpful in this instance. The changes I'm referring to happened about a year ago, but the overhead of managing beta so differently has become quite a burden that I'm going back to it now.

Comment: @JoshSmeaton - if you don't know "bad changesets" in beta, your situation is **extremely worse**. Ideas added to answer

Comment: New branch way you've described is exactly what I was wanting to do. Thanks for the extra information and clarification.

Answer (score 2):

If you were using Mercurial bookmarks, then yes.  Bookmarks are pointers to changesets, so you can force them to point anywhere you want (they're a lot like git branches if you know those).  Mercurial *named branches* though are indelible labels attached to *every* changeset.  When you're talking named branches the "head" is the "most tipward" (essentially newest) changeset that has that branch name, so you can't make an older changeset be the head without removing all of its ancestors that have that branch name.

Here's a diagram that might help.  For each changeset "branch" is its branch name (every changeset has one, but if it's `default` it's not shown in most UI contexts):

```
  [0]  (branch: default)
   |
  [1]  (branch: default)
   | \
  [2] \    (branch: default)
   |   [3]   (branch: beta)
  [4]   |    (branch: stable)
   |   [5]   (branch: beta
  [6]        (branch: stable)
```

In this diagram there are **2 topological heads**, changesets 6 and 5, but **3 total heads**, 2, 5, and 6.

Changeset 5 is the head of branch `beta` because it's the "newest" changeset w/ that branch name.  Changeset 6 is the head of branch `stable` because it's the "newest" changeset w/ that branch name.  And, changeset 2 is the head of branch `default` because it's the newest changeset w/ that name.

So, if I understand your question you can't make changeset 6, which is one branch stable, also be the head of branch `beta` because every changeset is on one and only one branch -- thus a single changeset can't be the head of two different named branches.

You do, however, have plenty of options:

Create a new changeset on branch beta that looks exactly like the current head of stable:

```
 hg checkout stable # makes the working directory look like changeset 6
 hg branch beta     # tell mercurial that the next changeset created should be on branch 'beta'
 hg commit         # creates changeset 7 on branch beta w/ contents of changeset 6
```

you may need to make some tiny change before you can commit there (to avoid "no changes"), but that's the gist of it.  Since your new changeset has the files from 6 but has the branch label 'beta' and is newer than 5... poof it's the new head of 'beta'.

or

Switch to using bookmarks -- they're more like how you're imagining branches work.  They're pointers to changesets and multiple pointers can point to the same changeset.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for the explanation. I wasn't sure if I could just rebranch 'over the top' or not. We've moved to using git - this is the only project still in hg - and the hg on our servers don't yet support bookmarks.

Comment: This ways **does not sync HEAD state** of branches, sorry

Comment: @LazyBadger, what do you mean? Will beta not look exactly like stable after this solution?

Comment: Thanks for the catch on default's head, @LazyBadger

Comment: @JoshSmeaton - sorry, no. Exported HEAD of beta will differ from exported HEAD of stable (because branches have different changesets in history). only tip revision after these three commands *may be* in beta (may be because hg `branch` **will not work** in this situation and `hg commit` will not commit /if there are not local changes/)